# php script can't access /tmp folder

Tags: php, file-permissions, centos7, tmp, tmpfs

I have no open_basedir, php can access /etc /usr /proc /home etc… but not /tmp.

tmpfs is mount on /tmp (/tmp type tmpfs (rw))
That's also the reason I want to use the /tmp folder.

My files are owned by http (user for nginx and php) and readable by everyone.

`sudo -u http cat /tmp/file` is working but anything inside a php script does not (like file_exist() or file()).

edit : the error show in log :

```
PHP Warning:  file(/tmp/ydlw/pid): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/http/ydlw/status.php on line 267
```

edit2: I tested the issue the other way. I made

```
touch("/tmp/boo");
file_exist("/tmp/boo");
```

and file_exist return true so the file is created. Then I watched inside /tmp and no "boo" file can be found there. That's what I was afraid, php do not «see» the mount point. Why is that and how can I fix that ?

Comment: What is the error returned by those PHP functions? What does PHP error log show?

Comment: I added the error log

Comment: Does this file `/tmp/ydlw/pid` exist in `/tmp`? If not, then that is the reason for the error message.

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 http http 343 23 juil. 10:12 /tmp/ydlw/pid

Comment: What is your Linux distribution and PHP version and where did you get PHP from?

Comment: arch linux and PHP 5.5.11 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2014 06:08:28) (from the official arch repo)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found off why, well, someone gave me the global hint.

It's neither the fault of php or tmpfs. The culprit was systemd and his security system `PrivateTmp`.

For those who get in the same issue that I did, the service php (and probably some others) have the `PrivateTmp` option to `true` in the systemd script (`/usr/lib/systemd/system`).

In that case, a new `/tmp` is created and isolated from the other one. All the data save inside are deleted once the service is stopped.

It's a security measure since `/tmp` can contain a lot a sensitive informations and php script are not always secure.

To deactivate this, simply copy the script inside `/etc/systemd/system` (to avoid overwriting of your changes after an update) and set `PrivateTmp` to `false`.

You can also set two or more services to share the same /tmp using `JoinsNamespaceOf`.

For more information > `man systemd.exec`

Comment: Thank you for that! I spent the whole day trying to figure that out. My brain is melting off my nose for trying so hard to figure that out.

Comment: I got confused on how exactly to do the steps but this has helped me:
https://www.maxoberberger.net/blog/2017/10/debian-9-private-tmp.html